# Object Subscriptable

Tags: python, web-scraping

While scraping the website, I am getting this error:

> links = [tag.a["href"] for tag in soup.find_all('strong')[1:-3]]
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Code:

```py
import requests
import concurrent.futures
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


HOST = "https://www.lyrics.com"
url = "https://www.lyrics.com/album/3769520/Now+20th+Anniversary%2C+Vol.+2"
# Parse the initial 'album' website
req = requests.get(url)
html = req.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')

# Find all song's links in 'album' site - these can be found under
# the 'strong' tab, and 'a' tab

links = [tag.a["href"] for tag in soup.find_all('strong')[1:-3]]
name = []

def getLyrics(url):
    url = HOST + url # songs are found on the HOST website
    # Parse 'song' site
    req = requests.get(url)
    html = req.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
    # Obtain the lyrics, which can be found under the 'pre' tab
    names = soup.find('h1',{"id":"lyric-title-text"})
    name.append((names.text)+".txt")
    return soup.find('pre').text

# Use multi-threading for faster performance - I'll give a small run down:
# max_workers = number of threads - we use an individual thread for each song
lyric = []
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(links)) as executor:
    # for every song...
    for j in range(len(links)):
        # run the 'getLyrics' method on an individual thread and get the lyrics

        lyrics = executor.submit(getLyrics, links[j]).result()
        print(lyrics)
        lyric.append(lyrics)
        # do whatever with the lyrics ... I simply printed them


for i in range(0 ,len(name)-1):
    File = open(name[i],"w")
    File.write(lyric[i])
    File.close()
```

I will be very thankful if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if `tag.a` is not `None`:

```
links = [tag.a['href'] for tag in soup.find_all('strong') if tag.a is not None][1:-3]
print(links)
# output ['/lyric/35873929/Tik+Tok+%5BNOW+33%5D', ...]
```

Comment: It is recommended to use `is` operator to compare an object with `None` as it is a singleton and `is` operator does not suffer from potential `__eq__()` override.

Comment: @Arkelis didn't really focus on performance here. thanks for your command. even ```if tag.a``` alone will work for this case.